# Php Framework which support multiple database instance at a time

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks, php

is theire any php Framework which will support multiple database instance @ single time.?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Zend Framework

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.multidb

I'd say it's safe to assume there are others. From memory, Doctrine supports multiple connections out-of-the-box so you can probably include Symfony.